# dplyr change group names within a column

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I use `dplyr` to change group names within a column?

Example Data:

```
library(dplyr)

# Iris dataset

dat <- iris

# Unqiue group names

unique(dat$Species)

# Attemp to change group names within the Species column (e.g., setosa = Group 1)

dat <- dat %>%
  mutate_at(Species, c('setosa' = 'Group 1',
                       'versicolor' = 'Group 2',
                       'virginica' = 'Group 3')) # throws error message: Error in check_dot_cols(.vars, .cols) : object 'Species' not found
```

There are plenty of examples on SO and google on how to change a column name using `dplyr` but I could not easily find an example of how to change group names within a column.

Comment: `library(dplyr); iris |> mutate(Species = case_match(Species, "setosa" ~ "group 1", "versicolor" = "group 2", .default = "others"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @JonSpring answer

```
dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(Species = case_match(Species,
                              "setosa" ~ "Group 1",
                              'versicolor' ~ 'Group 2',
                              'virginica' ~ 'Group 3'))
```